# OneNote API - get Notebooks stored in a organisation SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, onenote

I am currently using the Microsoft Graph Explorer to query the OneNote API to try and get Notebooks stored on a SharePoint site.

However, the Notebooks were created in teams but I can access them from a browser with our SharePoint url - not sure if this complicates anything?

The issue I am having is I am trying to get a set of Notebooks in a specific location (folder) and I am using the URL:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{organisationID}/onenote/notebooks` - this does return a successful response but it has no meaningful data, only links which also return nothing meaningful.

Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are after [`List pages` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onenote-list-pages?view=graph-rest-1.0) which returns a list of pages in a OneNote, the following  example demonstrates how to return Page `title` and `contentUrl` properties:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/onenote/pages?$select=title,contentUrl
```

where `contentUrl` returns the URL for the page's HTML content

Since *by design* notebook contains one or more notebook sections and each section in turn contains one or more pages, the following query demonstrates how to retrieve pages along with associated [`section`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/section?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [`notebook`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/notebook?view=graph-rest-1.0):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/onenote/pages?$expand=parentSection,parentNotebook
```